# Send a message to a specific channel with discord bot

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I am looking on how to send a message to a specific channel. I saw some people to use
`client.channels.cache.get('channelidhere').send('text')`
however that whole thing is an error for me.
Here is my whole code. working on a ticket bot for a friend not anything crazy.

````
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";

export default {
    category: 'Utility',
    description: 'Makes a support ticket.',
    slash: false,
    testOnly: true,

    callback: async({ message, args, client, guild, member }) => {
        let number = 0
        let timeout = 200
        const channel = await message.guild?.channels.create('Ticket', {
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.author,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
                }
            ],
        })
        channel?.setParent('956314466201514064')
        console.log(channel?.id)
        let setID = channel?.id
        
        client.channels.cache.get('956314466201514064').send('')
        

        
        
        
    }
} as ICommand```
````

Comment: You can use `message.guild.channels.cache.get('channel id').send('')` if that doesn't work

Comment: doesn't let me add .send onto that

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: (property) DataManager<string, AnyChannel, ChannelResolvable>.cache: Collection<string, AnyChannel>
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: I'm not sure about why the error is happening. Sorry

Comment: all good ty for trying

Comment: have you tried message.channel.send()?

Comment: Before I answer is the entire bot written using “Worn Off Keys” package? Or are you willing to use regular discord.js and node.js? I ask because it is so much easier to do it without WoK

Comment: I am willing to do it without, most of bot is written in wok but its an easy rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still looking for an answer here it is.

For regular messages do

```
message.guild.channels.cache.get('channel-id').send('message')
```

For interactions do

```
interaction.guild.channels.cache.get('channel-id').send('message')
```